# Update absolute reference if referenced cell is part of the copied data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

The main purpose of absolute references is that still point to the same cell after copy/pasted elsewhere. But what I want is, in case the cell referenced to is part of the data copied, the absolute reference is updated:

```
    | A | B        |
|---|---|----------|
| 1 | 1 | =$A1 + 1 |
```

B1 will have value 2.

Now, if I copy B1 to C1, I want C1 to reference A1 again. Excel will do this.

```
    | A | B        | C        |
|---|---|----------|----------|
| 1 | 1 | =$A1 + 1 | =$A1 + 1 |
```

But if I copy A1:B1 to C1:D1 (so I copy the referenced cell along with the referencing cells), Excel will still, as per absolute reference definition:

```
    | A | B        | C | D        |
|---|---|----------|---|----------|
| 1 | 1 | =$A1 + 1 | 1 | =$A1 + 1 |
```

But since I included A1 (which is referenced to) I want D1 to reference C1 instead of A1, so:

```
    | A | B        | C | D        |
|---|---|----------|---|----------|
| 1 | 1 | =$A1 + 1 | 1 | =$C1 + 1 |
```

Note that in this case it's relatively easy to manually work around it, but this is just an example, and for the real application, it concerns entire blocks of formulas.

The main reason I want to use an absolute reference is for a scenario like this (simplest form):

```
    | A | B         | C         |
|---|---|-----------|-----------|
| 1 |   |         4 |         2 |
|---|---|-----------|-----------|
| 2 | 1 | =$A2 + B1 | =$A2 + C1 |
```

Idea is to add the values above the formula to a common value $A2. You can copy cell B2 to C2, without having to manually update the formula; $A2 will remain $A1, while B1 will be updated to C1. Now if I want to copy this whole block A1:C2 to some other location, the formulas in the resp. pastes from B2 and C2, like in the previous examples, will still reference $A2, while I want them to reference the pasted cell from it. I could avoid this problem by not having the absolute reference to begin with. But then, I could not copy cell B2 to C2 anymore, since then C2 would say B2 + C1, while I wanted A2 + C1.

Anyone knows an easy and manageable way to address this?

Note, by the way, that Excel is not all that strict with absolute references; if you cut entire columns, it will update absolute references. If you cut/paste the referenced cell, it will update absolute references to it. I think above mentioned scenario should also be supported..

Comment: Are you familiar with R1C1 style references?

Comment: I am Jason, and thanks for the suggestion, but it does not solve my problem. If you feel otherwise, I would appreciate your solution in the shape of an answer. In its absolute form, B1 would contain '=RC2+1', and when copied to D1, it presents the same issue. Although not explicitly written so, the A1 notation is implicitly also a relative notation, and as such an interchangeable alternative notation, rather than something that has specific abilities, and it sadly does not address my issue.

Answer (score 1):

As denoted by the resounding silence to your question, this is not really doable because you're asking how to violate the very principle of absolute referencing. The point of absolute referencing is that references stay the same regardless of how you copy or fill the data across, and that is what it's designed to do.

At best, I have a work-around for you:

1. **Copy** the cells you want duplicated (along with their source data, as you've described above)
2. **Paste** them into another sheet in the same coordinates, (A1:C2 in your example) and you'll find you've got a set of copied formulae
   not referencing your original sheet.
3. **Select** your duplicated area and **Drag** it to the co-ordinates you want it to inhabit on your original sheet. This will 'update' the absolute references.
4. **Copy** and **Paste** the cells back to your original sheet, and they'll retain their 'updated' references.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I had seen this workaround elsewhere, it appears this is the only solution at this point. Note that the workaround also violates the principle of absolute referencing, in spite of your carefully chosen euphemism 'update' :). I would still like to have an option in Excel to choose and have the absolute reference 'updated' in case you copy the along the referenced cell. But this is not the platform..